# Adding tweening engine to my libgdx game project (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I've finished my first game with LibGDX (I'm using Eclipse). I run the game in the desktop launcher and it works. Now I want to run my game on android and IOS. From some guides I have read, I understood that for running the game on devices I must have the tween-engine libraries in my project. I tried but couldn't add the library to my project. Can someone help me?

(I already tried to do that at "add jars"; it shows me only my project and not the tween-engine library.)

Comment: Is your project structured with a core project and a desktop project? Is the tween engine library already in your core project?

Comment: On the Java Build Path page, instead of using "Add JARs" you should probably be using "Add External JARs", and browsing to the location of the JAR on your computer.

Comment: yes,there is a core and desktope projects but the tween engine library doesnt exists

Comment: Doesn't exist as a project in Eclipse, or doesn't exist on your filesystem at all?

Comment: why cannot you just export you project to eg Android from Eclipse? When you are starting the project with Libgdx .jar setup there's option to set Android and iOS (ofc Desktop also) and it will generate all you need to export version for devices

Comment: its OK if the tween engine jars will be only in the core project-->>JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY[JRE7]?(not in the libs folder)

Comment: !! If you are not using the tween library, there's no reason to put it in your project.

Comment: I use it,I want to know if it OK that those libreries would exists in project-->>JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY[JRE7]?(not in the libs folder)

Comment: If your android project depends on the core project, the library will be compiled into the android apk automatically, I believe. (I don't use Eclipse anymore because it causes so many headaches.)Have you tried exporting yet?